# Help with finding solution for utility function

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I'm brand new to Mathematica and having trouble finding a solution for Lh based on the first order condition.  I'm not sure if it is something I'm doing in Mathematica or something wrong with the equations.  Any suggestions?

```
Utility[x_] = (((x - Eta)^(1 - Theta))/(1 - Theta))
Harvest[Lh_] = (Lh)^Beta
Livestock[Nt_] = Nt*(1 + b - Delta*(T*Nt)/(L - Lh))
constraint = P*Harvest[Lh] - Alpha*Livestock[N]
Langragian = Utility[Livestock[N]] + Lambda*constraint
{FOC1 = D[Langragian, Lh], 
 FOC2 = D[Langragian, Lambda]}
sols = Solve[{FOC1 == 0, FOC2 == 0}, {Lh, Lambda}]
```

Comment: There are lots of beginner's mistakes. Functions should be defined with `:=` not `=`. You don't need `*`, just a space is enough. Symbols should not begin with a capital letter to avoid conflict with built-in symbols. You can't use `N` for example because it is a built-in function. You can suppress output by putting `;` at the end of each lines the prints something. You should not always use `:=` instead of `=` so be careful, read about the distinction in the documentation. I don't know which mistake makes the problem unsolvable if any of these, or if it's something else.

Comment: After correcting all the problems mentioned above, probably you won't get an answer. You've way too many free symbols, which means too many conditions to consider for Solve to be able to find an answer. Try to reduce the number of symbols or specify more conditions (signs, bounds, etc)

Comment: Thanks Anon and belisarius.  I suspect you are correct belisarius.  I will revise and see if providing more conditions works.  Thanks!

Comment: @anon You *can* define functions using `=`.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries I am still a newb after all. Anyways, you can also write `*`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a fixed-up version of your code. `Beta` is a built-in symbol and so is `N` so it's no wonder you are having trouble.

```
Utility[x_] := (((x - eta)^(1 - theta))/(1 - theta))
Harvest[Lh_] := (Lh)^beta
Livestock[Nt_] := Nt*(1 + b - delta*(t*Nt)/(lL - Lh))
constraint = p*Harvest[Lh] - alpha*Livestock[n];
 (* Lh^beta p - alpha n (1 + b - (delta n t)/(-Lh + lL)) *)

Langragian = Utility[Livestock[n]] + lambda*constraint

 (*  lambda (Lh^beta p - 
    alpha n (1 + b - (delta n t)/(-Lh + lL))) + (-eta + 
   n (1 + b - (delta n t)/(-Lh + lL)))^(1 - theta)/(1 - theta) *)
```

The deeper issue isn't your *Mathematica* code, it is your economics. The only choice variable seems to be `Lh`. You shouldn't be differentiating the Lagrangian with respect to `lambda`: it's the [multiplier on the constraint](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier). I think you need another choice variable, like `n`.

Try plugging in some parameters and seeing if that will solve with `NSolve`. Otherwise you may need to respecify your problem. It might not have a closed-form solution. A lot of economics doesn't.